# CategoryTree extension in MediaWiki won't update if I'm logged in

Tags: tree, categories, mediawiki

There's something really strange and buggy going on with **CategoryTree** updates.

Sometimes it does not want to update until I clear the cache in my browser, sometimes clearing the cache does not do anything.

Now I've stumbled upon another weird thing. I added a couple of pages in my custom namespace and they won't show up in the tree unless I log out. When I stay logged out the pages are there, but when I log in again they disappear.

Running `runJobs.php` script does not help.
The following options added to the `LocalSettings.php` do nothing as well:

```
#$wgCategoryTreeDisableCache = true;
#$wgEnableParserCache = false;
#$wgCachePages = false;
```

Please, help me to solve this annoying problem.

Comment: This is ridiculous. What I just did is: I deleted the contents of the subcategory page (which is [[Category:UpperLevelCategory]]), saved the page. Then I pasted the same contents and saved the page again. And now it works. This is very strange and I see no logic in this. I would like to solve this problem so my tree would update like it's supposed to.

Comment: The problem may be outside MediaWiki: in your reverse proxy cache.

Comment: @AlexanderMashin I did not install any proxies. Only what's been in MediaWiki package.